# Como obter o item que está no drag em um Drag&Drop do JQuery?

Tags: jquery, drag-n-drop

Quero saber como faço para obter o item que está em drag e assim eu poder alterar algumas propriedades dele. Segue o exemplo abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De acordo com o exemplo acima eu preciso alterar o item que estou arrastando e não o seu original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de duas formas:

```
$('#seletor').draggable({
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        //só acessar o ui.helper
        $(ui.helper).css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

ou você também pode pegar o evento via on e alterar seu clone

```
$('#seletor').on('drag', function( event, ui ) {
        //só acessar o ui.helper
        $(ui.helper).css('color', 'red');
});
```

segue o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/kJ5na/30/) :)

Comment: Pela documentação consegui achar. Mesmo assim valeu pela resposta. :D